# not:contains() Jquery Syntax issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have researched my problem and tried many different solutions yet I can't seem to find my issue, I assume it has something to do with the way I am calling my variable since it says syntax issue.

When first loading my results page, all results are displayed with a select drop down above those results. What I want to do is when a user clicks on an option on my drop down select is to filter the results based on what they select.

```
  $("#locale").on("change", function(){
  for(i = 0; i < storeTitles.length; i++){
    if(storeTitles[i].innerText != $("#locale > option:selected").text())
    $(".store-item:not(:contains(" + storeTitles[i].innerText + "))").hide();
     else
        $(".store-item:contains('" + storeTitles[i].innerText + "')").show();   
  }
});
```

I have tried many different ways..filter() and using :not() and :contains() combined. My code seems to work when I hard code a value into my :not(contains()). Can anyone spot my syntax issue or suggest a better way to go about this?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead

`if(~$("#TextBox1").val().indexOf($("#TextBox2").val()){//Contains True}`